# How to add line breaks to a Windows notification balloon?

Tags: python, windows, notifications, pywin32, system-tray

I have a tray bar application that displays notifications. Those are the regular Windows notifications, as a balloon over the application icon.

This is the basic code:

```
class TrayIconApplication:
    def __init__(self):
        [very long code to setup instance]

    def notify(self, message, title):
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY,
                         (self.hwnd, 0, NIF_INFO, WM_USER + 20,
                          self.hicon, 'Balloon Tooltip', message, 200,
                          title))
```

How do I add line breaks to the message, making it appear in multiple lines? I've tried `\n` and `\r\n`, but they don't seem to affect the text. `\r` alones is displayed as a single space and `\t` works as expected, but all messages are still displayed in only a single line.

Combinations of `\r` and `\n`, as well as their repetition, didn't yield any results.

Comment: Also, it doesn't seem to be HTML either. `<br>` was displayed literally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was changing the title, not the message. I mixed the order of parameters and was displaying a notification with title but empty message. And title lines cannot be broken, so it was ignoring all my attempts.

The difference is that the title is slightly larger, blue, and displayed in the same line as the close button.

As soon as I switched the parameters, `\n` started being accepted as the line break character and displaying a multi line balloon notification.

Comment: Stupid problem. I'm upvoting the alternative answers out of shame and thankfulness.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try \n\r? (the reverse of \r\n). I know it sounds stupid, but I've had unexpected results working with Windows Unicode character orderings. If all else fails try 0x0D, 0x0A or the reverse just to see how it responds.

Comment: Yes, to make sure I even made a long string of `\n\r\n\r\n\r`. It displayed as a single whitespace because of the trailing `\r`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the text for the system tray icon does not allow explicit new line character. If the text is too long, Windows will automatically move the text to next line as per whatever their row width is.

Comment: Tried a really long string, it just displayed the beginning and cut off the rest with no warning or `...` at the end.